# Style not working in class for any object?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, styles

Why doesn't my style change the background of any of these objects? I got annoyed and just assigned them to everything. Also why does it make two windows? I see that it's something to do with style being different then the style in the object's options... I feel like it's also with my class, am I suppose to `def _init_(self)` it? the class?

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("color1.TFrame", foreground = "black", background = "red")    
class main:

    parent = tk.Tk()
    n = ttk.Notebook(parent,style = "color1.TFrame")
    f1 = ttk.Frame(n,style = "color1.TFrame")   # first page tab
    f2 = ttk.Frame(n,style = "color1.TFrame")   # second page 2nd tab
    window = f1
    frame1 = ttk.Frame(window,style = "color1.TFrame")
    frame1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 200, pady = 150)
    frame2 = ttk.Frame(window)
    frame2.grid(row = 2, column = 1,padx = 200, pady = 150)

main()
```

Comment: i can get it to work without a class...

Comment: Nothing works, so the style has no reason to function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why nothing seems to appear and your styles don't work is because you're not actually drawing all of your widgets.

You never tell the below widgets to actually draw on your window:

- `n`
- `f1`
- `f2`

Additionally, a second window loads when you're calling `ttk.Style()` you haven't yet created a root window. This is explained much better than I could explain it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42599661/4528269).

By changing your program to the below you can see that the styles do actually work:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

class main:

    parent = tk.Tk()

    style = ttk.Style()
    style.configure("color1.TFrame", foreground = "black", background = "red")    

    n = ttk.Notebook(parent,style = "color1.TFrame")
    n.pack()
    f1 = ttk.Frame(n,style = "color1.TFrame")   # first page tab
    f2 = ttk.Frame(n,style = "color1.TFrame")   # second page 2nd tab
    window = f1
    f1.pack()
    f2.pack()
    frame1 = ttk.Frame(window,style = "color1.TFrame")
    frame1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 200, pady = 150)
    frame2 = ttk.Frame(window)
    frame2.grid(row = 2, column = 1,padx = 200, pady = 150)

main()
```

---

Arguably a better way of doing this would be something like the below:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("color1.TFrame", foreground = "black", background = "red")

class main:
    def __init__(self, root):
        n = ttk.Notebook(root, style = "color1.TFrame")
        f1 = ttk.Frame(n, style = "color1.TFrame")
        f2 = ttk.Frame(n, style = "color1.TFrame")

        n.pack()
        f1.pack()
        f2.pack()

        frame1 = ttk.Frame(f1, style = "color1.TFrame")
        frame2 = ttk.Frame(f1, style = "color1.TFrame")

        frame1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 200, pady = 150)
        frame2.grid(row = 2, column = 1,padx = 200, pady = 150)

main(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Although this is subjective and accomplishes the same goal.

Comment: Thank you for the response  I have it know :) i also get it now too instead of just copying it from somewhere.